# Nested Flexbox Scrolling - Partial Overflow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have an application with layers containing the following properties related to layout, each line is a layer. I've added relevant properties to positioning/display.

```
1. display: grid
2. display: flex
3. position: fixed, 100vh
4. display: flex, overflow: hidden
5. display: flex
6. display: flex

--------------- Splits into two columns, each one should scroll independently

7. display: flex, flex-grow: 1, overflow-y: scroll
8. display: flex, flex-grow: 1
```

The issue I'm seeing is that a few users are unable to scroll to the bottom of the children starting after the point where it splits into two columns. They can scroll partially, but about 30% of the remainder gets stuck off-screen.

I have been searching through chrome updates/issues related to the `min-height: auto` changes and cannot nail down the cause. I am completely unable to reproduce and am having a very hard time determining differences in the users' setup and my own.

Are there any known issue with nested flexboxes that would lead to one of the children be unable to scroll fully for *some* chrome users?

All theories so far have been relating to nesting of flexboxes causing a child at some level to not be contained, thus the hidden overflow of scrolling content.

I could use a new lead on any similar issues/workarounds/anything! Thanks!

Comment: it'd be better youd add code instead of explaining *about* it...

Comment: I added kind of a pseudo code chunk since the overall issue spans a lot of layers/code. Is there something I could change that would provide better info without rewriting the ~8 layers of html containers?